# How to get data from 'AudioSource.time' in Unity script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a Music Player app for Android in Unity3d. For show_currentPlayTime() function, I want to get AS.time value to show current playTime. For seek() function, I want to set AS.time value to get to that specific point of AudioClip. But, the problem is that AS.time is giving me 0.

I have tried setting AudioClip in AudioSource. It works that way, but the audio becomes distorted and shows abnormal behavior.

Variable Declaration:

```
public AudioSource AS;
[Range(0.0f, 1.0f)]

public Slider Volume;
public Slider slider;
bool isPlaying;


public List<AudioClip> AC = new List<AudioClip>();
int currentSong = 0;
```

Play Function:

```
public void Play()
{
    AS.Stop();
    AS.PlayOneShot(AC[currentSong]);

    //AS.clip = AC[currentSong]; ---
    //AS.Play(); ---
    //AS.clip = AC[currentSong]; ---
    //AS.PlayOneShot(AS.clip); ---

    clipInfo.text = AC[currentSong].name;
    Debug.Log(AC[currentSong].name);

    CancelInvoke();
    Invoke("Next", AC[currentSong].length);
    isPlaying = true;
}
```

The program runs with using --- lines, in above code, but with that, the audio becomes distorted.

Music Seek function:

```
public void MusicSlider()
{        
    AS.time = AC[currentSong].length * slider.value;
    slider.value = AS.time / AC[currentSong].length;
    Debug.Log(AS.time);
}
```

AS.time gives me value = 0.

Comment: What do you mean by distorted and abnormal behavior? Do you have exactly one `AudioListener`? Is it on the same GameObject as the `AudioSource`?

Comment: Are you saying you tried `public void Play()
    {
        AS.Stop();
        AS.clip = AC[currentSong];
        AS.Play();
        clipInfo.text = AC[currentSong].name;
        ...` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The [`AudioSource.Stop`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Stop.html) function stops the currently set Audio clip from playing

so you shouldn't be using [`PlayOneShot`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html) since this doesn't assign the `clip` value and  isn't stopped but played *parallel*. It is usually more used for playing soundeffects which may occure at the same time.

From [`AudioSource`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html)

> You can play a **single** audio clip using [`Play`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Play.html), [`Pause`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Pause.html) and [`Stop`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Stop.html) You can also adjust its volume while playing using the [`volume`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-volume.html) property, or seek using [`time`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-time.html). **Multiple** sounds can be played on one [`AudioSource`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.html) using [`PlayOneShot`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html).

[`AudioSource.time`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource-time.html) from the examples also only seems to work using [`Play`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Play.html) instead of [`PlayOneShot`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html) for the same reason.

In the commented code you are also mixing both [`Play`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Play.html) and [`PlayOneShot`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html). I guess what you called distorted is actually the clip **playing twice at the same time**. Your code should rather simply be

```
public void Play()
{
    AS.Stop();

    AS.clip = AC[currentSong];
    AS.Play();

    clipInfo.text = AC[currentSong].name;
    Debug.Log(AC[currentSong].name);

    // Don't know ofcourse what those methods do...
    CancelInvoke();
    Invoke("Next", AC[currentSong].length);
    isPlaying = true;
}
```

Comment: I think the problem was, the clip playing twice at the same time.